# GPS speed readings way off on Nougat

Tags: android, gps

Ever since updating my phone to Nought we're getting speed readings of 4-7 meters per second (which translate to speeds of around 22-25km/h) when before the update we used to get normal, realistic speeds.

Comparing with other GPS test apps out there, they are showing same result so it's not necessarily an implementations issue. Looking at running apps like runkeeper, mapmyrun, endomondo and such - they are giving correct pace calculation.

As of now I can't seem to pin point the source of the problem - GPS apps are showing high readings like my own app but running apps seem to overcome this issue.

Did anyone encounter such a phenomena, when upgrading to android N? My phone is Galaxy S6, upgraded from android M (Where it worked fine) to N where it started reading much higher values

How are the running apps don't get affected by it? is there a different implementation of speed/gps?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming, or is it just a general Android question?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm trying to figure out whether those running apps have implemented the location request any different so that they aren't affected by it.